# Android selector not working in custom view

Tags: android, selector, android-custom-view

I have the following simple selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_button_background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_button_background" />
</selector>
```

and the following activity's xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="settings"
        android:id="@+id/btnMainMenuSettings"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_selector"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.test.myapp.custom_views.CustomMainMenuButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="settings"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_selector"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/main_menu_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code:

```
public class CustomMainMenuButton extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomMainMenuButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_main_menu_button, this, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

The selector works fine for the button, but for the custom view I get only the normal state, the custom view is not clickable and nothing happens when I tap the custom view. Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout is not clickable, it is default state for all layouts. Use
`setClickable(true)` in custom view implementation or in xml layout `android:clickable="true"`

You should get something like:

```
<com.test.myapp.custom_views.CustomMainMenuButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="settings"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_selector"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change selector as :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_button_background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_button_background_pressed" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_button_background" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_menu_button_background_pressed" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! My selector suddenly stopped working (probably after I changed something but don't know what) and I tried every solution I could find here and yours finally did it.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Please add `android:clickable="true"` in

```
<com.test.myapp.custom_views.CustomMainMenuButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="settings"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_selector"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```